# If $P_n(x)$ has n real roots, then it's derivative has no complex roots

Tags: calculus, polynomials, roots, rolles-theorem

Usually, I would use Rolle's Theorem. Every polynomial is continuous and differentiable.

Using Rolle's Theorem, derivatives of functions have $n-1$ real roots:

Between every two consecutive roots $a$ and $b$, there will be point $c$, where $a<c<b$, that $f'(c)=0$. If the roots aren't consecutive, then the upper bound will be $n-1$.

But then $f(x)=x^2+1$ has no real roots, but its derivative has one real root: $f'(x)=2x=0, x=0$

Now my question is: How do I prove that there are no complex roots with Rolle's Theorem?

Note: This was in last years Calc exam, and im revising for my next one, so plz don't come at me saying this was in my lectures :)

Comment: Your example of $x^2+1$ has the implication backwards.  It is possible that a polynomial of degree $n$ with less than $n$ real roots has a derivative with $n-1$ real roots.  You are claiming that a polynomial of degree $n$ that does have $n$ real roots has a derivative with $n-1$ real roots.  You have identified $n-1$ intervals that each have a real root of the derivative in them.

Comment: I assume $n$ is the degree of the polynomial. Then its derivative has degree $n-1$, so we found all its roots on the real line by Rolle.

Comment: How many roots (real or complex) can an $n-1$ degree polynomial have?

Comment: @Henry Well, i suppose $n-2$ at most?

Comment: @GL02 - no - you have already shown in a particular case it is $n-1$

Comment: @Henry sorry for the misunderstanding. I thought you were talking about the derivative. Yeah, $n-1$.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yeah, I got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that you already have that, since $P_n$ is a $n$-degree polynomial, then it has at most $n$ roots (with repetition and including complex numbers). The same is true for $P_{n-1}$: polynomials of degree $n-1$ have $n-1$ roots, once you include repeated and complex roots. (This is known as the [fundamental theorem of algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra), or sometimes taken as a consequence of it.)

$P_n$ is given to have $n$ real roots. Using Rolle's theorem, you have deduced that $P_{n-1}$ (i.e. $P_n'$) has $n-1$ real roots. Since it is degree $n-1$, it cannot have any more roots than that.

> But then $f(x)=x^2+1$ has no real roots, but its derivative has one real root: $f'(x)=2x=0, x=0$

We are not concerned with this case. We are only concerned with the premise that **IF** $f$ is a polynomial, of degree $n$, with $n$ real roots, **THEN** we want to show that $f'$ is of degree $n-1$ with $n-1$ real roots.

$f(x) = x^2+1$ does not fit into the "if" statement, so we ignore that.

Comment: oh...lol thanks for clarifying. I was thinking this way too much. Seems easy!